# How to modify embed fields with a custom-coded Discord attendance bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm working on programming a custom attendance bot that organizes those who check "yes" gets their name added into their respective teams. There's two issues that I have at the minute:

Currently, it adds myself to my team as intended. However, it just sets the value to the current team as my name, meaning that if anyone from the same team checks in it replaces my name with theirs. I want to make it so it adds their name under mine, so multiple people from the same team can check in.

The second issue I have is that it the button system only works with a specific channel ID (see the line below)
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channelID');

I want to change this so it simply grabs the ID of the channel the embed/buttons are currently in, so there can be multiple check-ins for different events simultaneously.

All the code for the embed/current button system is below.

I apologize if these are simple fixes, my knowledge of JS isn't the best and I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to these issues online/with ChatGPT.

```
const customEmojiTeam1 = '<:Team1:team1ID>';
const customEmojiTeam2 = '<:Team2:team2ID>';
const customEmojiTeam3 = '<:Team3:team3ID>';
const customEmojiAvailable = '<:yes:availableID>';
const customEmojiUnavailable = '<:no:unavailableID>';
const customEmojiReserve = '<:Reserve:reserveID>';

client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'embed') {

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()

            .setTitle("Generic Title")
            .setDescription('Event 1 - timestamp)
            .setColor(0xffffff)
            .addFields({ 
                name: `${customEmojiTeam1} Team1`,
                value: '-',
            }, {
                name: `${customEmojiTeam2} Team2`,
                value: '-',
            }, {
                name: `${customEmojiTeam3} Team3`,
                value: '-',
            }, {
                name: `${customEmojiUnavailable} Unavailable`,
                value: '-',
            }, {
                name: `${customEmojiReserve} Reserves`,
                value: '-',
        });

        const yesButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setEmoji(customEmojiAvailable)
            .setCustomId('yes-button');

        const noButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setEmoji(customEmojiUnavailable)
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
            .setCustomId('no-button');

        const buttonRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(yesButton, noButton);

        interaction.reply({ content: 'Your check-in has been created. If you encounter any issues, please message @user.', ephemeral: true});
        interaction.channel.send({ content: `<@role1ID> <@role2ID>`, embeds: [embed], components: [buttonRow] });
    }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

    const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id);
    const team1Role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Team 1');
    const team2Role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Team 2');
    const team3Role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Team 3');
    const reserveRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Reserve');

    if (interaction.customId === 'yes-button') {
        if (member.roles.cache.has(team1Role.id)) {
            const team1Value = `- ${member.displayName}`;
            // Update the Team 2 field in the embed
            await updateEmbedField('Team 1', team1Value);
        } else if (member.roles.cache.has(team2Role.id)) {
            const team2Value = `- ${member.displayName}`;
            // Update the Team 2 field in the embed
            await updateEmbedField('Team 2', team2Value);
        }
        else if (member.roles.cache.has(team3Role.id)) {
            const team3Value = `- ${member.displayName}`;
            // Update the Team 3 field in the embed
            await updateEmbedField('Team 3', team3Value);
        }
        else if (member.roles.cache.has(reserveRole.id)) {
            const reserveValue = `- ${member.displayName}`;
            // Update the Reserves field in the embed
            await updateEmbedField('Reserves', reserveValue);
        }
});

async function updateEmbedField(roleName, value) {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channelID');
    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 });
    const embedMessage = messages.first();

    // Find the field with the specified role name and update its value
    const field = embedMessage.embeds[0].fields.find(f => f.name.includes(roleName));
    if (field) {
        field.value = value;
    }

    // Update the embed message
    await embedMessage.edit({ embeds: [embedMessage.embeds[0]] });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly:**

You have a syntax error at your embed creation. You forgot the ending quotation mark `.setDescription('Event 1 - timestamp)`.

It should be `.setDescription('Event 1 - timestamp')`

---

**Question 1:**

To add new participants instead of resetting the value to whoever clicked it, you'll need to change the value that you assign to `field.value` by adding a little string concatenation like this:

```js
async function updateEmbedField(channel, roleName, value) {
    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 });
    const embedMessage = messages.first();
                
    // Find the field with the specified role name and update its value
    const field = embedMessage.embeds[0].fields.find(f => f.name.includes(roleName));

    if (field) {
        field.value = field.value === "-" ? `${value}` : `${field.value}\n${value}`;
    }
                
    // Update the embed message
    await embedMessage.edit({ embeds: [embedMessage.embeds[0]] });
}
```

We also modified `updateEmbedField()` by adding a channel parameter so that you could get the channel of the buttons of the embed.

---

**Question 2:**

You can grab the channel where the button was clicked in by using the interaction data that was passed on the `interactionCreate` event handler.

Tip:

- Instead of having two event listeners for the same `interactionCreate` event, you can combine them into one for a more efficient and concise code.

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
        // Do your chat input command logic here
    }
    else if (interaction.isButton()) {
        // For your second question, you can grab the channel/channel Id of the button like this
        let channel = interaction.channel;     // The channel itself
        let channelId = interaction.channelId; // The channel Id
        let member = interaction.member;

        // When you call your updateEmbedValue(), pass the channel as the first argument
        // updateEmbedValue(channel, "Team1", member.displayName);
        // Do your on button interaction logic here
    }
});
```

**Lastly:**

Don't forget to apply `await` to methods like: `interaction.reply` and `interaction.channel.send` as they're promises, and if not awaited properly, could cause unpredictable behavior with the order of execution of your program's code. Also, if ever there's an error with them, they won't get caught by a try catch block due to their asynchronous nature, so make sure to apply `await`.